# Subclass Abstract Class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to intercept the step-up and step-down actions of the spinbox buttons to initiate some code to run. However, I believe I have to subclass the abstract class, but I'm not entirely certain how to go about doing it correctly.

I haven't tried to code it yet, was unable to find any good examples through googling. I believe have the right direction in the spinbox.py file, but not sure what I need to do exactly.

spinboxui.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 150)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.groupBox)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

spinbox.py

```py
import sys
from spinboxui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def do_something(self):
        pass


class QAbstractSpinBox(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox):

    def __init__(self):
        QAbstractSpinBox.__init__(self)

    def stepUp(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    spinbox = Main()
    spinbox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'd like to intercept the step up command, run a bit of code, then allow the spinbox to perform. I am using the spinbox as a page turner for a plain text edit field, as the spin box is incremented or decremented, it changes the "page" on the plain text editor. I have code that needs to run on the page it was last on before moving to the next "page".

Comment: Why not just use its `valueChanged` signal?

Comment: I tried. But, it triggers the function too late. For example, I'm on "page 1", as I'm going to change to "page 2", the function triggers, and only affects the "page 2" and not the prior page. I need this function to trigger for step ups and downs.

Comment: Yeah, typo, but doesn't affect the handling of the triggers. I'll fix the typo.

Comment: You mean that you want spinbox to go up and down by Abstractclass instead of `valueChanged` signal?

Comment: So, QAbstractSpinBox has trigger slots for stepUp and stepDown. According to the wiki, Steps up by one linestep Calling this slot is analogous to calling stepBy (1);. If I'm reading this correctly, this is the slot that actually makes the spinbox stepup by one digit.

What I need to do is intercept the stepup. For instance, you can click the up arrow to increase the value. As the user clicks the button, I need a function to run, once the function finishes, it will step up the value.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to:

- Inherit from QAbstractSpinBox because creating a class with the same name from which QSpinBox inherits will not change its behavior
- Overwrite the `stepUp()` method because that method only calls the `stepBy()` method by the developer, instead you must overwrite the `stepBy()` method and verify that the steps are positive or 1 as you wish.

spinbox.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class SpinBox(QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
    def stepBy(self, steps):
        if steps > 0:
            print("execute function")
        super(SpinBox, self).stepBy(steps)
```

spinboxui.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from spinbox import SpinBox


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 150)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.spinBox = SpinBox(self.groupBox)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

main.py

```py
import sys
from spinboxui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    spinbox = Main()
    spinbox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

If you want to execute the function in main.py, it is best to create a signal:

spinbox.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class SpinBox(QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
    upSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def stepBy(self, steps):
        if steps > 0:
            self.upSignal.emit()
        super(SpinBox, self).stepBy(steps)
```

main.py

```py
import sys
from spinboxui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.upSignal.connect(self.on_up)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_up(self):
        print("up")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    spinbox = Main()
    spinbox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```